# How to pass custom values from paging params while syncfusion grid export?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, syncfusion

I'm using syncfusion grid in my project. Need to export the data to an excel file from syncfusion button. Also I need to send a dropdown value to the controller action while syncfusion exporting the data to an excel file.

I followed the following demo which syncfusion gives,

http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/asp.net%20mvc/default.htm#!documents/throughgridbuilder40.htm

but can't find anything about how to pass custom parameter to the controller action.

Could someone please say me a way to pass the value from view to action on grid exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  view page you can pass the string value in mappers and you can get the passed value in the controller post action

**View page**

@{string value= "passed";}

@(Html.Syncfusion().Grid("GenericListGrid")

```
. .. . ...........
```

.Mappers(map => **{ map.ExportExcelAction("ExportToExcel", new { passstring = value** }); })

//passed the string  value to the post action...
     )

**Controller**

public ActionResult ExportToExcel(PagingParams args,string  **passstring**) 
//you can get the passed value  here

```
    {
        var storedvalue = passstring;
```

return data.GridExportToExcel("GridExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Excel2007,args.ExportOption);
        }

Comment: Can we pass this parameter value when we call that export function on a seperate button click